# View controller won't initialise

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load a view controller. It is created in code, not interface builder. However when I initialise it I get nil.

The view controller is a subclass of another class which contains a couple of properties.

```
weak var p = MyViewController()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `weak`, to keep `strong` reference to the new object.

Because if there is nothing hold `strong` reference to the object, It will be `deinit`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried and it works. Strangely weak works in objective-c.